# How to find the derivative of $(e^{-t} +e^t)^3$

Tags: calculus

How to find the derivative of
$$g(x) =(e^{-t} + e^t)^3 $$

The answer in my math book is; $ 3(e^{-t} + e^t)^2 (-e^{-t} + e^t)$

I've been stuck for days on these problems. By the answer I would assume there is a rule I am missing. I think I have all the rules for differentiation but none seem to apply. Is there a rule for this; if not how do I solve to find that answer?

Comment: Good news: the answer in your book is emphatically wrong. The correct answer is 

$$3(e^{-t} + e^t)^2(\color{red}{-}e^{-t} + e^t)$$

Comment: Chain rule I bet.

Comment: Look at the **Chain Rule** for calculating the derivative of a composition of functions.

Comment: see chain rule, for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule also the answer seems to be wrong, should be $-e^{-t}$ in the last parenthesis

Comment: I forgot about the chain rule!!! Thanks all- how are you guys so good at math?

Edited the correct answer from my math book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $$g(t) = (e^{-t}+e^t)^3$$

Apply chain rule;

$$g'(t) = 3(e^{-t}+e^t)^2\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-t}+e^t)$$

$$= 3(e^{-t}+e^t)^2(-e^{-t}+e^t)$$

which is the answer provided in your book.

Comment: Thank you for showing that extra step. It helped. I was confused at first about why e switched to a negative when finding the derivative but I figured it out.

Comment: Great! Yeah, it's just $$\frac{d}{dt}e^{-t} = -e^{-t}$$ which coincidentally is the result of another use of the chain rule :)

Comment: would it be wrong to use $(d/dt)e^u = e^u * u'$?

Comment: That's exactly how you would do it.

Comment: Awesome! That rule is derived from the chain rule too?

Comment: It *is* the chain rule. First, you derive the function with respect to the inner function, then you derive the inner function itself. Muliply the two results, and you have your answer.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see now. Thanks again :).

Answer (score 0):

IF you're stuck with chain rule, just use binomial expansion: $(a+b)^3 = a^3 +3 a^2 b +3 a b^2 +b^3$ and life will become easier.

Comment: life is much easier with the correct application of chain rule. try finding the derivative of $(e^t + e^-t)^{10}$

Comment: @abel - Agreed. The chain rule *must* be learned in any calculus endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$

So  the derivative of $f(g(x))^n$ is $$nf(g(x))^{n-1} g'(x)$$

Just apply this formula to your problem and you are done.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been downvoted twice :-(

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x) =(e^{-t} + e^t)^3=8\cosh^3t\\
g'(x)=24\cosh^2t\sinh t=24(e^t+e^{-t})^2(e^t-t^{-t})$$